# Terminal Server closes Delphi socket

Tags: sockets, delphi, server, terminal

I have a Delphi application that runs from Terminal Server. Said application connects to another one that is on my local windows computer through a ClientSocket.
The problem is that after a certain time of inactivity the socket is disconnected. Any ideas?.
Thank you.

I don't know what to try. If I run both applications on my local machine I have no problems.

Comment: This could be caused by an active network element (such as a router). Activity can be simulated by sending 'empty' data from time to time. Which exact error message is shown?

Comment: Have you tried turning on TCP keep-alives on the socket? See [`setsockopt(SO_KEEPALIVE)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/so-keepalive) and [`WSAIoctl(SIO_KEEPALIVE_VALS)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/sio-keepalive-vals).

Comment: The error is 10053

Comment: I'm going to try setsockopt(SO_KEEPALIVE) and I'll tell you, thanks

Comment: For now it seems to have been resolved. I have done what both of you have suggested:
1- from time to time I send a signal to maintain the connection and
2- I set the setsockopt(SO_KEEPALIVE) to keep the connection active

Thank you very much you two